# Angular 5 navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

Considering I'm on route

```
/parentOne/param1/param2/child
```

Is there any way for me to navigate to this another route, without passing the entire path (`/param1/param2/child`)?

```
/parentTwo/param1/param2/child
```

The solution I have today:

```
const path = this.router.url.replace(regex, 'parentTwo');
this.router.navigate([path]);
```

The solution I wish I could implement:

```
this.router.navigate(['parentTwo', '...']);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. I believe what you want is something like detail page routing. Your routing will be like `:parent/param1/param2/child`. Reference here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-hero-detail-route

Comment: I don't think you can, btw there is an option for relative paths like `  this.router.navigate([yyy], { relativeTo: a route });`

Comment: If your parent is a parameter, then whatever Tin mentioned is fine. But if your parent is a static string then, whatever you are already doing is good, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Check out NavigationExtras.
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras
Using relativeTo and relative path, you can navigate

```
 go() {
    this.router.navigate(['../list'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

Example:

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'p1', component: P1,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: P1C
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'p2', component: P2,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: P2C
      }
    ]
  },
];

this.r.navigate(['../../p1', '2'], {relativeTo: this.a})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current url in a component like this for instance:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute; router: Router) {      
   const url: Observable<string> = route.url;
  }
}
```

You can then use `this.router.navigate(url)` to navigate to specific url.